# the Registration system in Codeforce，why the number after the name isn't right?

Tags: java

The question is on Codeforce:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1LAJ.png)

```java
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = S.nextInt();
        String[] input = new String[n];
        S.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            boolean N = true;
            input[i] = S.nextLine();// input a name
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.println("OK");
            }
            else {
                int counter = 0;
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {// test if there is a repeation
                    if (Objects.equals(input[i], input[j]) ||
                        Objects.equals(input[i], input[j] + 1) ||
                        Objects.equals(input[i], input[j] + 2) ||
                        Objects.equals(input[i], input[j] + 3) ||
                        Objects.equals(input[i], input[j] + 4) ||
                        Objects.equals(input[i], input[j] + 5) ||
                        Objects.equals(input[i], input[j] + 6) ||
                        Objects.equals(input[i], input[j] + 7) ||
                        Objects.equals(input[i], input[j] + 8) ||
                        Objects.equals(input[i], input[j] + 9)) {
                        counter++;
                        N = false;
                    }
                }
                if (N) {
                    System.out.println("OK");
                }
                else {
                    input[i] = input[i] + counter;
                    System.out.println(input[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the outcome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwCnT.png)

No matter how many *A* I input, they are just *A* or *A1*. Why?

How to make the number after the name correct?

Comment: `counter` and the repetition check seem fishy (and more complicated than it should be). Simplify by maintaining a count for each registered name. Hint - use a `Map<String, Integer>`.  Another advide - use better names for your variables, what is `N` for example... You yourself won't be sure what it represents an hour after you wrote the code.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to initialize `counter` before the outer `for` loop. That's why the generated name is always *A1*. I recommend that you debug your code in order to verify this.
- You iterate through the array of names so you only need to compare `input[i]` with `input[j]`. No need for the extra comparisons.

Here is your code with my corrections as described above.

```java
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n =S.nextInt();
        String[] input=new String[n];
        S.nextLine();
        int counter=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            boolean N=true;
            input[i]=S.nextLine();//input a name
            if(i==0){
                System.out.println("OK");
            }else {
                for (int j = i-1; j >=0; j--) {//test if there is a repeation
                    if (Objects.equals(input[i], input[j])) {
                        counter++;
                        N=false;
                    }
                }
                if(N){
                    System.out.println("OK");
                }else {
                    input[i] = input[i] + counter;
                    System.out.println(input[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is output from a sample run:

```
3
A
OK
A
A1
A
A2
```

However, this is still not correct – even though it gives correct output for your sample input.

Consider a different sample run:

```
6
a
OK
b
OK
a
a1
b
b2
c
OK
a
a3
```

As you can see, it does not provide correct results. The second *b* should be *b1* and not *b2* and the last *a* should be *a2* and not *a3*.

You actually need a separate counter for every, unique name. Hence I suggest using a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html). The [map] key will be the name and the [map] value will be its, associated counter.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = S.nextInt();
        Map<String, Integer> names = new HashMap<>();
        String name;
        S.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            name = S.nextLine(); // input a name
            Integer temp = names.get(name);
            if (temp == null) {
                names.put(name, 0);
                System.out.println("OK");
            }
            else {
                temp++;
                names.put(name, temp);
                System.out.println(name + temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A sample run:

```
6
a
OK
b
OK
a
a1
b
b1
c
OK
a
a2
```

Comment: You could simplify the if-else part a bit with `Map.compute()` - `Integer nameCount = names.compute(name, (key, old) -> old == null ? 0 : old + 1);` and printing - `System.out.println(nameCount == 0 ? "OK" : name + nameCount);`.